# Getting java.io.EOFException when javax.faces.ViewState value is changed in Fiddler

Tags: jsf, exception, custom-error-pages

In Our application, If we trace the request in Fiddler after successful login to the application the first POST request contains a parameter javax.faces.viewState with some encrypted value.
Now, in fiddler if I try to change the value of the ViewState parameter it is causing EOFException and printing a stack trace in the browser.

How can I prevent to display the Exception in the browser and showing customized message to the user.
In web.xml I have already done the below changes:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

But, it didn't work. Can anybody please help me to get rid of the issue.

Comment: in web.xml:   I have tried using the below code                                                                 <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>                                                                                                              But it didn't work. So,what I did I have implemented a Filter class which store the parameter value.                                                                                     if(ViewState!=null)

Comment: In Fiddler whenever I am going to change the value or injecting some values in the javax.faces.ViewState parameter,I am getting Exception and the status code for http response is 200.